# What casues firebase deploy to fail this way?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

My functions have been deploying fine. Then one morning when i went to deploy i started receving this error on about half my functions.  What is causing this and how should i resolve it?

````
Build failed: {"cacheStats": [{"status": "MISS", "hash": "faf64a157eae1ded8e6b3245bbccc5f0de78ebc473617f08cfcf4a630f1fc21", "type": "docker_layer_cache", "level": "global"},
{"status": "HIT", "hash": "faf64a157eae1ded8e6b3245bbccc5f0e278ebc473617f08cfcf4a630f1fc21", "type": "docker_layer_cache", "level": "project"}]}```
````

Comment: If you're having problems deploying functions using the Firebase CLI, don't post to Stack Overflow. Contact Firebase support directly. https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely cause is the [outage](https://status.cloud.google.com/) that started a few hours ago (January 7th. 2020), affecting several Cloud Function deployments with errors such as `Build failed` and `INVALID_ARGUMENT`. Engineering is aware and they're working on it. If you're unsure or wish to stay up to date on it, [contact support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact?visit_id=637140091775563839-1350076797&rd=1).